# MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline Optimization

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation pipeline as mentioned below. Considering that there can be hundreds of thousands of documents on which I want to apply this pipeline, I have questions on how it can be optimized. Below are my questions:

1.) What is the most optimal index that be applied to the match query. Should I have an index = myArray.tags.tagKey, myArray.tags.tagValue, myArray.someRules.count, myArray.entryTime OR should I create separate indexes for each of these fields. What is the best way to do this?

2.) If you see my pipeline, I am applying match operator twice to filter the documents: Once in the beginning of pipeline to get the benefit of my index. Second, I am using it after unwinding operation to filter the specific array elements of the array "myArray". Is there any way I can combine them. In other words, can array elements be filtered using $match aggregation operator?

Here is an example of my document:

```
{
"_id" : "8001409457639",
"myArray" : [ 
    {
        "entryID" : ObjectId("5101ab1116b12614fb083022"),
        "requestID" : "adb0d2asdfbe10",
        "owner" : "ABC",
        "version" : 1,
        "requestType" : "1",
        "someRules" : {
            "count" : 0,
            "somethingElse" : 11
        },
        "entryTime" : ISODate("2015-09-22T19:25:19.014Z"),
        "tags" : [ 
            {
                "tagKey" : "Owner",
                "tagValue" : "ABC"
            }, 
            {
                "tagKey" : "Request Type",
                "tagValue" : "1"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "entryID" : ObjectId("5101a111c6b12614fb083022"),
        "requestID" : "fc057asdf16480",
        "owner" : "ABC",
        "version" : 1,
        "requestType" : "1",
        "someRules" : {
            "count" : 10,
            "somethingElse" : 0
        },
        "entryTime" : ISODate("2015-09-22T19:44:26.558Z"),
        "tags" : [ 
            {
                "tagKey" : "Owner",
                "tagValue" : "ABC"
            }, 
            {
                "tagKey" : "Request Type",
                "tagValue" : "1"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "entryID" : ObjectId("5101b111c6b12614fb083011"),
        "requestID" : "40c7a0ads2dd8c2",
        "owner" : "ABC",
        "version" : 1,
        "requestType" : "1",
        "someRules" : {
            "count" : 10,
            "somethingElse" : 0
        },
        "entryTime" : ISODate("2015-09-22T20:24:15.347Z"),
        "tags" : [ 
            {
                "tagKey" : "Owner",
                "tagValue" : "ABC"
            }, 
            {
                "tagKey" : "Request Type",
                "tagValue" : "1"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"lockAcquiredBy" : "james",
"lockStartTime" : ISODate("2015-11-18T22:36:05.266Z")
}
```

This is my aggregation pipeline:

```
[{
    "$match": {
        "$and": [{
            "$or": [{
                "myArray.tags": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "tagKey": "Owner",
                        "tagValue": "ABC"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "myArray.tags": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "tagKey": "Owner",
                        "tagValue": "DEF"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }, {
            "$or": [{
                "myArray.tags": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "tagKey": "Request Type",
                        "tagValue": "4"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "myArray.tags": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "tagKey": "Request Type",
                        "tagValue": "Retry"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }],
        "myArray.someRules.count": 0,
        "myArray.entryTime": {
            "$gte": {
                "$date": "2016-01-05T01:59:07.763Z"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$myArray"
}, {
    "$match": {
        "$and": [{
            "$or": [{
                "myArray.tags": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "tagKey": "Owner",
                        "tagValue": "ABC"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "myArray.tags": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "tagKey": "Owner",
                        "tagValue": "DEF"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }, {
            "$or": [{
                "myArray.tags": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "tagKey": "Request Type",
                        "tagValue": "4"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "myArray.tags": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "tagKey": "Request Type",
                        "tagValue": "Retry"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }],
        "myArray.someRules.count": 0,
        "myArray.entryTime": {
            "$gte": {
                "$date": "2016-01-05T01:59:07.763Z"
            }
        }
    }
}
// More steps in the pipeline.
]
```

Comment: why are you using second match and why are you using unwind

Comment: Hi @rummykhan: That is because I want to filter elements of the array "myArray" based on the tags. My understanding is that we cannot do that with match because it will only filter the complete documents and it cannot remove some array elements for me. So i am using unwind and then I have multiple documents which I can filter using match. The reason I am match twice is because the first match will be able to use the index and at least will be able to filter a good chuck of documents.